# PHP dynamic page variable passing without submit button

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query which will return a module code from the database. Let's say I have a template file (i.e. course.php) and what I would like to achieve is that I want to create a dynamic page with the name of the module code returned by the query (i.e. course.php?course=CS1231). However I don't have a submit button in course.php which allows me to pass that variable using GET method into URL. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Please do some research about possible solutions before coming here. You might want to check out Google searches on AJAX and/or JQuery if you want to submit something without a page reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you don't need a submit button to use $_GET if your URL looks like this course.php?course=CS1231

You can just redirect to the page e.g.

```
<?php
$variable='course.php?course=CS1231'; #Whatever is returned by your database
header('Location: http://www.example.com/'.$variable);
exit;
?>
```

And in course.php you use $_GET['course'].

Comment: Your suggestion was the one I am looking for. It gave me an idea on how I could achieve this. Thank you!